# Query results in three different result sets instead of one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need a month list for three years , but I get three different result sets instead of one list (so with 36 lines).
I'm quite new to SQL server so I could be completely wrong in the logic here below ;).

```
declare @yearlist table (value int)
declare @year int
INSERT INTO @yearlist VALUES (year(getdate())-1)
INSERT INTO @yearlist VALUES (year(getdate())+0)
INSERT INTO @yearlist VALUES (year(getdate())+1)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT Value FROM @yearlist
OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @year   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
  ;with mths as(
    select 1 as mth, DATENAME(MONTH, cast(@year*100+1 as varchar) + '01')  as monthname, RIGHT(CAST(@year AS CHAR(4)),2) AS yr2, @year as yr 
    union all
    select mth+1, DATENAME(MONTH, cast(@year*100+(mth+1) as varchar) + '01'), RIGHT(CAST(@year AS CHAR(4)),2) AS yr2, @year as yr 
    from mths where mth<12
  )
  select yr2 + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), mth), 2) as monthID,  
  * from mths  

  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @year   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

But this is the needed data:

```
1701    January     2017
1702    February    2017
1703    March       2017
1704    April       2017
1705    May         2017
etc...
1908    August      2019
1909    September   2019
1910    October     2019
1911    November    2019
1912    December    2019
```

Where the year must be the past, current and next year (dynamic).

Comment: This solution really does not need a cursor. This is definitely an XY question; you're trying to fix the cursor where the problem is in fact that you are using a cursor. Let's take a step back and understand what your real goal is here. Provide sample data and expected results (as **formatted** `text` or DDL and DML statements), and explain your logic. We can then help you get rid of that awful Cursor change it into a dataset approach, which also returns one dataset.

Comment: *P.s. a bug bare of mine: `;` is a statement terminator, it's supposed to go at the end of (every) statement, it's not a beginninator, or part of the `WITH` clause. :)*

Comment: There is an [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53867475/edit) button, please make use of it. That data is unformatted, and unreadable.

Comment: That data still isn't usable. Have a look [here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/).

Comment: What about the sample data though? Again, have a look at my comments and the the article I linked.

Comment: Hi @Larnu I don't have any sample data. There is no data where this is based on, as the variable is just the current date, and the info is only based on this date. I want to create an on the fly list of months of this, last and next year for some selection purposes for end users.

Comment: OH, so you jsut want the months and years for 2017-2019. I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you if this is going to be a repeating thing, where the values could change, you may well want a [Calendar Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/).

Otherwise, you could use an inline tally table:

```
DECLARE @StartYear int = 2017,
        @EndYear int = 2019;

DECLARE @StartDate date = CONVERT(varchar(4),@StartYear) + '0101',
        @EndDate date = DATEADD(YEAR,1,CONVERT(varchar(4),@EndYear) + '0101');


WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1 --10
         CROSS JOIN N N2 --100
         CROSS JOIN N N3 --1000
    )
SELECT RIGHT(DATEPART(YEAR, V.D),2) + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(MONTH,V.D)),2) AS YearMonth,
       DATENAME(MONTH, V.D) AS [MonthName],
       DATEPART(YEAR, V.D) AS [Year]
FROM Tally T
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEADD(MONTH, T.I, @StartDate))) V(D)
WHERE V.D < @EndDate;
```

This solution covers you for up to 1000 months (just over 83 years), so should be more than enough.

Comment: Wow thanks @Larnu, that works like a charm! I'm not yet understanding how it actually works, but that will come later.

Comment: Understanding how it works is really important @MrSiezen, it's you who needs to support the above SQL not me. Which part are you struggling with? Don't forget, as well, to mark the answer as a solution if it solved the problem for you, so that future readers with the same/similar problem know that the answer helped resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested on past, current and next year, following query should work for you

```
SELECT RIGHT(YEAR(GETDATE())-1, 2) + right ('00'+ltrim(str(mth )),2 ) ,  DateName( month , DateAdd( month , mth , 0 ) - 1 ), YEAR(GETDATE())-1  FROM  (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) AS X(mth)
UNION ALL
SELECT RIGHT(YEAR(GETDATE()), 2) + right ('00'+ltrim(str(mth )),2 ), DateName( month , DateAdd( month , mth , 0 ) - 1 ), YEAR(GETDATE())  FROM  (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) AS X(mth)
UNION ALL
SELECT RIGHT(YEAR(GETDATE())+1, 2) + right ('00'+ltrim(str(mth )),2 ), DateName( month , DateAdd( month , mth , 0 ) - 1 ), YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1  FROM  (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) AS X(mth)
```

Comment: Hi @S.Jose, that works like a charm as well, and is, for me, much more understandable!